# function returns null before assigning value

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-test

**Hello can anyone help me to overcome this issue? the function doesn't wait till data fetched from the database. it simply returns null object..**

```
Future<Admin> loginVerification() async {
  Admin admin;
  _databaseReference.child("admin").onValue.listen((event){
   admin= Admin.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot);
 });
 return admin;
}
```

Comment: Check this https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Comment: use `await loginVerification()` or `loginVerification().then(...)`

Comment: during function call?

Comment: Sir, I tried as you said but it returns null only..

Comment: `var event = await _databaseReference.child("admin").onValue.first; return Admin.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot);`

Comment: sir, this works whether this continuously listens for the changes?

Comment: no, it returns one value: `Future<Admin>` - isnt it what you want?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214398/discussion-between-yogish-shenoy-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0):

You can't have await here as methods not returning Future, The way you have to do this Like

```
return _databaseReference.child('admin').onValue.firstWhere((element) => Admin.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot));
```

Comment: Yes sir any solution for that?

Comment: below  this line do your stuff  admin= Admin.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot);

Comment: Sir i am using bloc to manage the states, and i hav to return value to bloc to tell inform app about the next state based on the validation.

Comment: I have to return some values but if returns null first before the validation

Comment: @YogishShenoy: Edited the answer, Hope that will work you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214410/discussion-between-yogish-shenoy-and-jitsm555).